# How do i swap the old links in my a links href attribute values with the ones in my newLink array?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get my a links to get the attribute value from my newLink array as it new attribute value to no avail.  Any help would be welcome.

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</a></li 
    <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/">AMAZON</a></li> 
    <li><a href="https://www.ebay.com/">EBAY</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.pointekonline.com/">POINTEK</a></li>
  </ul>
```

```
ul.onclick = function (e) {
      let newLink =["https://www.barcablaugranes.com/","https://managingmadrid.com/","https://bavariafootballwork.com/","https://wagnh.com/"]
      let ass = querySelectorAll('a');
           if (e.target.nodeName != 'A') return;
            for(let i = 0; i < ass.length; i++){
              return ass[i].href = links[i]
            }
           return false;
         }
```

Comment: use decent names for variables. What is `ass.lenght`

Comment: To be clear: you want to change the `href` attributes to each corresponding link in the `newLink` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had errors in your code. I have fixed them. Now it should be working.

**Your Errors**

- Why wouldn't want the links to be updated as soon as the site is loaded?
- Why looking for event target.nodeName without preventing the default behaviour of links?
- Why using return in event listener?
- Missing `document` before querySelector

```js
let newLink = ["https://www.barcablaugranes.com/", "https://managingmadrid.com/", "https://bavariafootballwork.com/", "https://wagnh.com/"]
let ass = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let i = 0; i < ass.length; i++) {
  ass[i].href = newLink[i]
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
  <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/">AMAZON</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.ebay.com/">EBAY</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.pointekonline.com/">POINTEK</a></li>
</ul>
```